# Is all metadata necessary for decryption included in a symmetrically encrypted GNU Privacy Guard message?

Tags: gnupg

Suppose I symmetrically encrypt a file with a passphrase using GNU Privacy Guard and send it to a friend. I use the latest version and all the defaults, so AES-128 encryption is used, with the salt and `s2k_count` used for the password derivation function automatically generated.

I then tell my friend the passphrase and ask them to open it.

Are the salt, S2K type, `s2k_count`, and so on included in the file somehow, so that my friend can decrypt the file knowing only the password?

I suspect the answer is affirmative but I have not been able to find it in the documentation.

Comment: Your question title and body ask two different questions. Are you asking about which metadata in general is included? Or if specifically these three are included?

Comment: @MechMK1 I have tried to clarify the title.

Comment: @alligator: Aren't you basically asking if knowledge of the password is sufficient to decrypt a file which was encrypted by `gpg -c`, i.e. every other information necessary to decrypt are contained in the encrypted file? If this is your question then the answer is "yes". If this is not your question please clarify what is different in your question.

Comment: See rfc4880 sections 5.3 and (as referenced) 3.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes, it is.

You can verify this easily by yourself by encrypting a file with `gpg -c filename` and then decrypting that file with the password you have specified. No further parameters are required.

Comment: Thanks. It was difficult for me to verify this due to the gpg password caching mechanism.

Comment: @alligator This feature is called use agent and [can be disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47273922/purpose-of-gpg-agent-in-gpg2)

Comment: Please note I tried to upvote your answer but can't until my reputation is higher. Thank you.

Comment: @alligator That is fine, I'm not here for internet points anyways. I'm glad my answer was helpful for you!

Comment: @alligator to work around caching for something like this, you could `sudo` run the command as a different user